# Changing the page of an embeded .pdf using a link

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, hyperlink

I can use "#page=[pageNumber]" after the src to ensure the pdf opens to the respective page, but I don't understand how to use a variable in place of the [pageNumber] and change the variable when a tab/button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is looping over each of the links with `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, and attaching a click handler to each of the links. You can then target the clicked link's target by splitting on the `href` with `this.href.split("=")[1]`.

In the following example, I'm assigning `this.href.split("=")[1]` to a variable `clicked`, which you can reference whenever you want to know the **last** link that was clicked.

```js
var clicked;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clicked = this.href.split("=")[1];
    console.log("You clicked link: " + clicked);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="?page=1">Page 1</a>
<a href="?page=2">Page 2</a>
<a href="?page=3">Page 3</a>
```

Note that the above example uses `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the click action from actually going through. Simply remove that line to allow the clicks to open the relevant pages in your actual code; the `clicked` variable will still get updated.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Why `il` instead of `i < links.length`?

Comment: @Bright -- Good question. To be honest, I copied the generic JavaScript `for` loop from a sample to save on writing it out, without actually double-checking it. While the above method still works the same way, you're right in that it could be optimised. Good spotting, and I'll update that now :)

Comment: <embed id="pdf" src="Manual.pdf "> This is what I am using to embed the pdf into my page. Using what you have provided appears to reload the page while passing the variable in the url. But how do I modify the embedded src for the pdf? Thank you.